# C++ How to detect the State of Window using handler whether its in Fullscreen or not?

Tags: c++, winforms, winapi, fullscreen

I need to identify a application(such games) window's state whether it running in fullscreen or not.

Is there any  similar [window styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) such WS_MAXIMIZE,WS_MINIMIZE to check the full screen state of Window's Handler ?

Comment: Use GetWindowPlacement(), showCmd field.  I *think* it can be called on a window owned by another process, you'll find out.  Of course you cannot count on it still being accurate after the call.

Answer (score 1):

In windows most applications **don't have** true fullscreen windows they just fill your entire screen and being called "fullscreen" it is true to a certain extent but they are ordinary windows.
Thing is that Windows doesn't have a flag or a state for this, altho using D3D is diffrent since it can run in a true fullscreen mode which needs other methods to detect.

Your best bet to tell if its a fullscreen window is to compare the window size to the display's size. Like [GetWindowRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ( or [GetClientRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ) to get the window's size then to do it properly you need know know which display ( in case there are multiple monitors ) the window is originated from with [MonitorFromWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) then you can query the monitor's size in pixels with [GetMonitorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ( in the [MONITORINFO structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145065%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you will get the screen's size in pixels ).

Now you know the screen's size and the window's size from this point it's up to you how you decide if it's fullscreen, you may compare for an exact match or give it some threshold and also check the position of the window.

You can also check a widely used window flag which is [WS_EX_TOPMOST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it's mostly used by OpenGL apps to give the illusion of a real fullscreen app, I would say if the window is WS_EX_TOPMOST **and** it's size is the same as the screen size you can be 90% sure it is a fullscreen game or something like that.
I can't really give you any advice however on how to detect D3D fullscreen apps.

Comment: thanks. as u mentioned "In windows most applications don't have true fullscreen windows they just fill your entire screen. In a scenario where the applications such games running in "true" fullscreen mode, I could not get the "handle" of that  fullscreen application. I tried "GetDC" and "GetWindowDC". It didnt work.Please give any solution for this issue.

Comment: As far as I know that is called the overlay mode which is in fact the real fullscreen mode all I can say is that you should look around on MSDN especially in Direct3D. Because as far as I know its specific to that.